# google play subscription expirytime always keeps changing

Tags: android, node.js, google-api, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to get the user-app subscription details on my node server, using the google-play-android developers API. I can see payment details and etc, but the "expiryTimeMillis" keeps on changing. My app has subscriptions of 1 Month and 1 Year, but the "expiryTimeMillis" returns the expiry time of the current date always. Every call shows the "expiryTimeMillis" incremented by 30 minutes from the previous. Here's the response i get:

```
enter code here{
    "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
    "startTimeMillis": "1526551258808",
    "expiryTimeMillis": "1526551965486",
    "autoRenewing": true,
    "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
    "priceAmountMicros": "10000000",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "developerPayload": "inapp:test2:7305d346-c289-4e56-a251-698d3cdea241:dev_1",
    "paymentState": 1,
    "orderId": "GPA.3347-1830-1569-93306..0",
    "purchaseType": 0
}
```

Why does "expiryTimeMillis" always change and is not stable? Also, why doesn't it show "expiryTimeMillis" as 1 Month from today or 1 Year from today?

Thanks

Comment: Hey @johndoesit, have you solved this problem? Have you identified why that happened? I have the same problem with one of my subscriptions and can not find any information about reason of such behaviour